# Network/Socket Connection Issue

Tags: windows, networking, ping, bridge, sockets

**Problem**
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.12(Client) can NOT be established (See Fig. 1).

**Tests**
Test 1: "Ping"
`ping 192.168.1.2 -S 192.168.1.1` -> Success
`ping 192.168.1.12 -S 192.168.1.11` -> Success
`ping 192.168.1.12 -S 192.168.1.1` -> Fail

Test 2: "Socket Connection"
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.2(Client) can be be established.
Datas have been received and sent successfully.
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.12(Client) can NOT be established.
BeginAccept's callback at SocketSever has NEVER been called.

Test 3: "Alternate Endpoint Devices"
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.2(Client) can be be established.
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.12(Client) can NOT be established.
Therefore, Both of Endpoint Devices work finely (Actually they are same products)

Test 4: "Another network structure"
On another network structure, all works finely (See Fig. 2).
However i can not take this solution because i can not put a HUB between Left and Right USB-ETHERNET.

**My assumption**
This problem caused by that both networks are isolated and can't interact each other.
If there is any Windows application works like "HUB", it might resolve this case.

**Any suggestions or solutions?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should probably just enable bridging on Windows.

Comment: Are they supposed to be two networks or are they supposed to be a single network? Having a machine on two networks with overlapping IP addresses is painful.

Comment: To Ron: Thank you for an advice! I'm currently studying bridging on Windows... Maybe this will work. To David: I don't use identical IP addresses on this whole networks. One network consists of 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2, and another one consists of 192.168.1.11 and 192.168.1.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two options to make this work.

As Ron has mentioned above, the bridge is the first solution, which makes your computer a hub. Any packet is broadcasted in a single network segment.

Another options is to put these two interfaces into different subnets, then enable the ip forwarding (routing) on the computer. Then your computer becomes a router, which means that it will route the packets between these two subnet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The first one "Bridging" worked finely. But when i turn on it, DHCP Server will be delayed to feed ip to endpoint(Normally:3sec -> Bridged:10sec), and since endpoint device will be rebooted automatically in 10sec, still Socket Connection can not be established. Anyway, the new issue is not being discussed and your and Ron's post were completely solving my basic problem.

Comment: I got another progress. By your 2nd method, it works completely over delayed issue which i mentioned the previous comment. Thanks a lot.